# how to deal with the resolution in the phonegap

Tags: css, html, mobile, cordova, resolution

I'm using phonegap to develop a small demo which will run on the Android device. And the resolution of my device is 1280*720, so I create a canvas which is 1280*720 to fill the whole screen and draw a picture with the same size.But I find it's too big to show in my advice, I must adjust this to 640*360. But it is very blurred.How can I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin:0 !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="360" height="640"></canvas>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            prepareCanvas();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```